# Why does the Vuetify navigation drawer fly out at large screen size? How do I prevent it from happening?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the following Vuetify toolbar with a navigation drawer.  This my first attempt at building a Vue app with Vuetify  At smaller screen sizes it behaves as expected.  Once the screen width hits the large breakpoint (1264 px), the drawer flys out.  Using Chrome Version 72.0.3626.109 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I can't find any reference to this being expected behavior in the docs let alone how to prevent it.  Is there a simple way to stop this behavior?

My `app.vue`

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="sidebar" app>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-toolbar height=48 app>
      <v-toolbar-side-icon class="hidden-sm-and-up" @click="sidebar = !sidebar">
      </v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>{{ appTitle }}</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-xs-only">
        <v-btn to="/" flat>Home</v-btn>
        <v-btn to="/about" flat>About</v-btn>
      </v-toolbar-items>
    </v-toolbar>
    <v-content>
      <router-view/>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        appTitle: 'VueTodo',
        sidebar: false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a prop to handle this exact behaviour `disable-resize-watcher`:

```
<v-navigation-drawer disable-resize-watcher v-model="sidebar" app>
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers

Answer (score 2):

Try those changes:

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="sidebar" app temporary>
<v-toolbar-side-icon @click="sidebar = !sidebar">
```

Also you can check the documentation about it here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers#props

Comment: This does work but `disable-resize-watcher` seems to be more semantically correct.  I am afraid your answer might have side effects down the road

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

There is a significant role of app attribute in v-navigation-drawer. You can please remove it and check if you find it helpful.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30927583)